# CASE Statement with condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

I think this will be easier to show an example first and then explain:

```
SELECT P.ID,
(CASE WHEN PC.NewCostPrice IS NULL 
THEN P.Cost ELSE MAX(PC.Date) PC.NewCostPrice
END)
FROM price AS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN priceChange as PC
ON P.ID = PC.ID
```

So in the example, if the NewCostPrice IS NULL, meaning there wasn't a price change, then I want the normal cost (P.Cost). However, if there was a price change, I want the most recent (MAX(Date)) price change. I am not sure how to incorporate that into the CASE statement.

I feel like it can be done with a subquery and having clause but that didn't really work out when I tried. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `ID` a primary key in the mentioned tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way

```
SELECT   distinct P.ID,
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 PC1.NewCostPrice FROM  priceChange as PC1 WHERE PC1.ID = p.id ORDER BY PC1.Date DESC), p.cost)
    FROM price AS P
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 approaches you might consider - I would test both to see which performs better for your situation.

1. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in subquery to find most recent price change of all price changes, then join that to prices to get correct price.
2. Use correlated subquery (many ways of this, either in `SELECT` as in other answer or with `OUTER APPLY`) to get only most recent price change for each row of prices

If your price table is very large and you are getting a large number of prices at once, method #1 will likely be better so the correlated subquery doesn't run for every single row of the result set.

If your final query pulls back a relatively small number of records instead of huge result sets for your server, then the correlated subquery could be better for you.

**1. The ROW_NUMBER() approach**

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    COALESCE(PC.NewCostPrice, P.Cost) AS LatestPrice
FROM Price AS P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RowId,
            NewCostPrice
        FROM PriceChange
    ) PC
        ON P.ID = PC.ID
            AND PC.RowId = 1 -- Only most recent
```

**2a. Correlated subquery (`SELECT`)**

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    COALESCE((
        SELECT TOP 1
            NewCostPrice
        FROM PriceChange PC
        WHERE PC.ID = P.ID
        ORDER BY PC.[Date] DESC
    ), P.Cost) AS LatestPrice
FROM Price AS P
```

**2b. Correlated subquery with `OUTER APPLY`**

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    COALESCE(PC.NewCostPrice, P.Cost) AS LatestPrice
FROM Price AS P
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            NewCostPrice
        FROM PriceChange PC
        WHERE PC.ID = P.ID
        ORDER BY PC.[Date] DESC
    ) PC
```

Whether you use 2a or 2b is more likely a preference in how you want to maintain the query going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume `PC.ID` is not a primary key, or it makes no sense to join with `ID` while there could be different price on the same item.

From your query I assume you just want to fetch the latest `NewCostPrice` sorted by `Date`, by joining `priceChange`

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN PC.NewCostPrice IS NULL THEN P.Cost
        ELSE PC.NewCostPrice                    
    END AS NewPrice
FROM
    price AS P
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) as rk FROM priceChange) PC ON P.ID = PC.ID AND PC.rk = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
    SELECT   P.ID
            ,(CASE 
                WHEN PC.NewCostPrice IS NULL 
                  THEN P.Cost 
                ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 PC1.NewCostPrice
                      FROM  priceChange PC1
                      WHERE PC1.ID = PC.ID
                      GROUP BY  PC1.NewCostPrice, PC1.Date
ORDER BY PC1.Date DESC
                      )
               END
              )
    FROM price AS P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN priceChange as PC
    ON P.ID = PC.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sam! However, that didn't really work out, it was selecting the wrong values... I'll have to look into why, maybe the wrong date I am guessing. Also I had to add a `SELECT TOP 1` to the subquery and the HAVING clause needed a condition so I added `HAVING PC1.Date = MAX(PC1.Date)`